# query byte[] in petapoco

Tags: petapoco

I have a query in which I have to select Data which is of type byte.

```
byte[] data
```

My query is as follows:

```
private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(int fileID){
    return Connection.db.Query<dynamic>("select Data from [File] where id = @0",  fileID.ToString());
}

byte[] actual = file.GetData();
```

and I want to find the length as follows:

```
actual.Length
```

The problem with the above is that I have to find the length but GetData returns a dynamic object actual.

How can I retrieve the Data and have its length?
Is there a better way to query byte[] in PetaPoco?

Comment: What is the db type? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this:

```
var d = db.Fetch<dynamic>("select id, data from bytetable");
foreach (var item in d)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.id + "-" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(item.data) + "-" item.data.Length);
}
```

where bytetable is defined:

```
create table bytetable (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    data image (or varbinary(max)),
)
```

and it works as expected.
The data variable is indeed a byte[].

Comment: With the above I can read only item.data, how to read the length of item.data? data is defined as varbinary(MAX) instead of image